# gedit error message 8828

Tags: gedit

I wanted to edit my `php.ini` file, so I type `sudo gedit php.ini` but I got following error message:

```
Inung

** (gedit:8828): WARNING **: Could not load Gedit repository: Typelib file for namespace 'GtkSource', version '3.0' not found

(gedit:8828): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/myuser/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
```

It looks like missing `GtkSource` for this. Any suggestions to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `gksu gedit php.ini`, if gksu is not installed by default then run this `sudo apt-get install gksu` command to install it.

This error will happen if you're trying to open a graphical application using sudo.Use `gksu` instead of `sudo` to open graphical application like `gedit`,`nautilus`,etc.

Comment: Thanks a million for the information and help, Regards, inung